# Array operation using map or collect in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dictionary, collect

I have an array `@a = [[9, 15], [], []]`

I need to make it [9,15] using map method. How it is possible?

I have tried the below statement,

```
@a.map{|array| array.collect{|element| element} if array.any?}.compact
```

But giving [[9,15]] as output. Can anyone just help me out. Thanks :)-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about the requirements, but this gives the desired result

```
[[9, 15], [], []].flatten
```

Comment: is it a proper ruby method?

Comment: If that is the answer, @RajeshCO, maybe you should accept it?

Comment: Sure, I was waiting for it